# running select query in ms access 2007 vba and assign the resulting value to a textbox

Tags: forms, sql-server-2005, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need to run a sql query and the resulting value is assigned to a textbox in the form.
I am using docmd.runsql sql to run this query.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim SQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(Me.txtInstalledQuantity) Then
SQL = "select count(tblequipmentbase.id)AS CountInstalledQuantity FROM (tblequipmentbase INNER JOIN     tblequipmentparts ON tblequipmentbase.id=tblequipmentparts.idconnect) INNER JOIN tblparts ON tblequipmentparts.idpart=tblparts.id where tblparts.id= " & txtQueryID.Value & ";"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
Me.txtInstalledQuantity = rs!CountInstalledQuantity
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

The error is in the runsql command.

Comment: Not quite sure why you are performing a RunSQL() call anyway? From your .OpenRecordset command, you should already have the data you want.

Comment: even if I remove the Docmd.RunSQL SQl,it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
Me.txtInstalledQuantity = rs.Fields("CountInstalledQuantity").Value
```

Comment: I have never found it necessary to include value to reference a field in a recordset. rs!fieldname is commonly used.

Comment: Completely agree Remou. I just always prefer to be explicit especially when dealing with default properties like .Value. Just depends on your style / code standards I guess.

Comment: The Form_Current() belongs to a subform.txtQueryID is a textbox on the same form but its value comes from the mainform.I fave made a public variable to get this value form the mainform and it's assigned to a public function which returns a string.The code works uptill here if I delete the code in Form_Current() of the subform.Even if the subform loads before the mainform it should atleast take the value from the mainform.

Comment: Also, if I give direct value instead of &Me.txtQueryID it works. I do not understand why nothing works when put together.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a query, let us call it Equipment:

```
 SELECT eb.id 
 FROM (tblequipmentbase eb
 INNER JOIN tblequipmentparts ep
 ON eb.id=ep.idconnect) 
 INNER JOIN tblparts p
 ON ep.idpart=p.id
```

You can then use this query in several ways, for example, you can set a textbox control source to:

```
= DCount("eb.id","Equipment","p.ID=" & txtQueryID)
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168244(v=office.10).aspx

```
Me.txtInstalledQuantity = DCount("eb.id","Equipment","p.ID=" & txtQueryID)
```

Or

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

s = "SELECT Count(eb.id) As EqC " _
  & "FROM (tblequipmentbase eb " _
  & "INNER JOIN tblequipmentparts ep " _
  & "ON eb.id=ep.idconnect)  " _
  & "INNER JOIN tblparts p " _
  & "ON ep.idpart=p.id " _
  & "WHERE p.id = " & Me.txtQueryID

Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(s)

Me.txtInstalledQuantity = rs!EqC
```

Comment: I can't use an expression in the control source as this textbox is editable.Users can enter data which is then saved in the database.

Comment: First, create the query and check if it works, next ensure that  Me.txtQueryID has a value. It is always best to say what not working involves, error messages, etc.

Comment: By any chance is txtQueryID a label, rather than a textbox? Because if it is, you need Caption to get the contents.

Comment: txtQueryID is a textbox.Can't I pass a variable instead of a textbox value?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you are having problems, and it is simpler to just refer to the textbox. You can add a breakpoint and examine the string s to ensure that it is correct, you can also use debug.print to print to the immediate window and test the string in the query design window to ensure a record is returned.